# How can I upgrade phpMyAdmin to 4.7.*?

Tags: 16.04, phpmyadmin

I want to update phpMyAdmin to lastes version. I tried commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but phpMyAdmin is still `4.6.6deb1+deb.cihar.com~xenial.2`. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It always amazes me how people use PPAs like it's nothing, without even paying any attention to [what's in them](https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin)...

Answer (score 2):

As far I can understand you can simply download it as [phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-all-languages.tar.gz](https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.7.7/phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-all-languages.tar.gz).

Then extract somewhere to `/var/www/html/` or to other VirtualHost directory and use it (follow [installation procedure](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/qa_4_7/setup.html#quick-install)).

In such case you do not need the great power of APT.

Answer (score 1):

The repository you've added carries the following disclaimer:

> Note: This repository is currently a bit behind as I struggle to find time to update it to 4.7 series, see https://bugs.debian.org/879741. There are no severe security vulnerabilities in the 4.6.6 currently packaged here (https://www.phpmyadmin.net/security/PMASA-2017-9/ applies only to 4.7 series). The only major problem is that 4.6.6 doesn't work properly with PHP 7.2.

He's even further behind now, seeing as how the current release is 4.8.X...